# Microsoft Graph - Delete Access Package Assignment

Tags: javascript, python, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API Beta version to delete an access package. However, for deleting an access package, I need first to remove all its assignments.
For doing this, I found on the official doc the accessPackageAssignment object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/accesspackageassignment?view=graph-rest-beta).
When I perform a get request on the assignment:

```
result = azureAdBeta.get('/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageAssignments/' + accessPackageAssignmentId)
```

the response is successful:

> {'@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageAssignments/$entity',
> 'accessPackageId': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
> 'assignmentPolicyId': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
> 'assignmentState': 'Delivered',
> 'assignmentStatus': 'Delivered',
> 'catalogId': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
> 'expiredDateTime': None,
> 'id': '2ad2eb61-9baa-45b9-a700-bfef425d7aef',
> 'isExtended': False,
> 'schedule': {'expiration': {'duration': None,
> 'endDateTime': '2022-01-20T23:00:00Z',
> 'type': 'afterDateTime'},
> 'recurrence': None,
> 'startDateTime': '2021-12-15T11:16:04.663Z'},
> 'targetId': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'}

However, when I perform a delete request:

```
result = azureAdBeta.delete('/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageAssignments/' + accessPackageAssignmentId)
```

I get the following error:

> {'error': {'code': '',
> 'innerError': {'client-request-id': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
> 'date': '2021-12-15T11:32:37',
> 'request-id': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'},
> 'message': 'No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '
> "'https://igaelm-asev3-ecapi-neu.igaelm-asev3-environment-neu.p.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/accessPackageAssignments('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')'."}}

I suppose this error is due to fact that in doc no delete method is mentioned for the accessPackageAssignment object.

So how can I delete an access package assignment via Microsoft Graph?

Comment: Please refer this documentation link for reference as it aptly states the commands to delete an access package : - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/accesspackage-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Hi Kartik, The documentation about the Delete Access package API states that "You cannot delete an access package if it has any accessPackageAssignment."
So hiw can I delete the accessPackageAssignment?

Comment: Hi @Alessandro, please refer this documentation link for reference which clearly states how to remove the concerned access package assignment through Microsoft graph identity governance powershell module : - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-access-package-assignments#remove-an-assignment-with-powershell

Comment: beta API for accessPackageAssignments is still under development and currently it doesn't support DELETE method.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't support DELETE method, but since it is an assignment, it can surely be removed through the above method for the respective assigned resource.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can remove an Access package assignment through Microsoft graph powershell module in the following way: -

First view all the access package assignments through the below powershell command -

```
   ‘ Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "EntitlementManagement.Read.All"
     Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
     $accesspackage = Get-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackage -DisplayNameEq "Marketing Campaign"
     $assignments = Get-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackageAssignment -AccessPackageId $accesspackage.Id -ExpandProperty target -All -ErrorAction Stop
     $assignments | ft Id,AssignmentState,TargetId,{$_.Target.DisplayName} ’
```

The above command will display all the assignments for the access package as stated above which correspond to the stated display name. Once, all the access package assignments for the stated access package are displayed, execute the below command to remove the access package assignment for the concerned access package by entering the correct access packageID. Also, enter the correct targetID(objectID of the user/group/resource) of the assignment to be removed.

```
     ‘ Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "EntitlementManagement.ReadWrite.All"
        Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
       $assignments = Get-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackageAssignment -Filter 
        "accessPackageId eq '9f573551-f8e2-48f4-bf48-06efbb37c7b8' and 
        assignmentState eq 'Delivered'" -All -ErrorAction Stop
        $toRemove = $assignments | Where-Object {$_.targetId -eq '76fd6e6a-c390- 
       42f0-879e-93ca093321e7'}
       $req = New-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackageAssignmentRequest - 
        AccessPackageAssignmentId $toRemove.Id -RequestType "AdminRemove" ’
```

This will remove the access package assignment for the concerned access package.

Note: - You will have to install the Microsoft Graph Identity Governance module in powershell for executing the above commands. To install the module, please run this command in elevated powershell – ‘Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Governance’

Also, you can remove the access package assignment through Microsoft Graph from an application JSON file. To do so, refer the following link and replace the value of "requestType": "AdminAdd" to "requestType": "AdminRemove"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/accesspackageassignmentrequest-post?view=graph-rest-beta&preserve-view=true&tabs=http#request

Please refer the below link also for reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-access-package-assignments#remove-an-assignment-programmatically